# Can not retrieve Birth Date from Address Book & show in table view cell in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsarray, addressbook, tablecell

I want to retrieve the birth date from address book & display it in table view cell. I can retrieve the birth date from address book but when I show it in table view cell , app crashes. 
Here is my code

```
// in viewDidLoad
 birthdateString = [ContactDetails getBirthDate:record];


 +(NSString*)getBirthDate:(ABRecordRef)record{

    NSString *birthdateString=[(NSDate*)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonBirthdayProperty) description];
    NSArray *array=[birthdateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    birthdateString=[array objectAtIndex:0] ;
    NSLog(@"birthDay: %@",birthdateString);
    return birthdateString;
}

// in cellForRowAtIndexPath
cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CELL_ID] autorelease];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=birthdateString;
```

Console log when NSZombieEnabled

```
*** -[CFString isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6eb5520
```

Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the full code so cant tell , but check for nil value during debugging . There is some NSString which is not getting memory allocation.
Just got the answer

```
// in cellForRowAtIndexPath
cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2          reuseIdentifier:CELL_ID] autorelease];
  NSString *brithdateString=[self getBrithDate:record];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=birthdateString;
```

You are using brithdateString which was local and deallocated after the getBrithDate method was called

Comment: But I can see the output of NSLog(@"birthDay: %@",birthdateString);
correctly. Problem occured while showing it in table cell.

Comment: i think now it should work you were using brithdatestring which was nill during the loading of table view

Answer (score 0):

try this

> ```
> CFDateRef birthDate = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);
> NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
> if(birthDate)
> {
>    if (dateFormatter == nil) {
>    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
>    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
>    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
> } 
> NSString* birthDay = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:(NSDate*)birthDate ];
> NSLog(@"birthDay: %@",birthDay);
> if (dateFormatter != nil)
> [dateFormatter release];
> CFRelease(birthDate);
> ```